# Import 3rd party lib file to visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studios and trying to use http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/
But I can't seem to import the library...
I just added the file to the project and tried to use it in the Book.js(View). 
But it doesn't seem to work.. 
Am I missing any steps?

Comment: Are you using asp.net mvc?

Comment: @dinomix yes asp.net mvc!

Answer (score 0):

Add the qrcodejs file to a bundle in your App_Start/BundleConfig.cs and then render the bundle in the view where you need it or the default bundle in your layout file.

Also make sure the js file is in your Scripts folder.

Comment: Is there any easier explanation? I am very confused!

Comment: Here are some step by step instructions, the scripts they are adding are different but concept is the same: http://blog.falafel.com/adding-your-own-scripts-and-style-sheets-to-mvc-4-bundles/